# how to save h264 stream into .264 file

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtmp

I'm using nginx-rtmp-module build hls server, when I play it on safari, it does not shows image,then i use this command `ffmpeg -i rtmp://192.168.4.213/hls/testH264 -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -segment_time 5 output%03d.ts`, it shows `missing picture in access unit with size 28184`,so i think maybe the raw h264 stream has some problem,then i directly save the h264 stream into .264 file,but when i play the .264 file with vlc,the screen is fuzzy,help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should use binary type to save file